# How to use VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER to set install location in Wix 3.10

Tags: wix

Using Wix 3.10, I'm trying to install an extension in the common extensions folder. However I haven't been able to figure out how to use the `VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER` property.

I have the following inside the `Product` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Test" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MSFT" UpgradeCode="2c2ba7d9-387a-4da9-b7f2-82d737b839b6" Codepage="1252">
    <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <PropertyRef Id="VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER" />

    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER">
        <Directory Id="TSTDIR" Name="test" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="FeatureId" Title="test components">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="TestComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="TestComponents" Directory="TSTDIR">
      <Component Id="VS_Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeScript.EditorFeatures.dll">
        <File Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TypeScript.Internal" Source="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TypeScript.Internal.dll" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But that results in the following error:

`"Test.wixproj" (default target) (1) -> (Link target) ->

test.wxs(22): error LGHT0231: The component 'VS_Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TypeScript.EditorFeatures.dll' has a key file  with path 'TARGETDIR\test\microsoft.visualstudio.typescript.internal.dll'.
Since this path is not rooted in one of the standard directories (like ProgramFilesFolder), this component does not fit the criteria for having an automatically generated guid.

(This error may also occur if a path contains a likely standard directory such as nesting a directory with name "Common Files" under ProgramFilesFolder.) [Test.wixproj]`

My question is how do I suppres this error, since `VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER` is rooted under `Program Files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you just need to add `ProgramFilesFolder` between `TARGETDIR` and `VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER` this change to make this work.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="VS2015_ROOT_FOLDER">
```